# Catching exceptions by `const` value in C++. Compilers diverge

Tags: c++, exception, initialization, language-lawyer

In the following program, struct `A` has both copy-constructor `A(const A&)` and a constructor from lvalue-reference `A(A&)`. Then an object of `A` is thrown and then caught as `const A`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A&) { std::cout << "A(A&) "; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "A(const A&) "; }
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw A{};
    }
    catch ( const A ) {
    }
}
```

All compilers accept the program.

As far as I understand exception objects are never cv-qualified, and handler variables are initialized from an lvalue that refers to them. So one could expect that `A(A&)` constructor be preferred in `catch`. And indeed Clang does so.

But GCC prefers copy constructor printing `A(const A&)`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1an5M7rWh

Even more weird thing happens in Visual Studio 2019 16.11.7, which prints nothing during program execution.

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: To allow for polymorphism you should be catching exceptions by reference and therefore avoid the copying anyway

Comment: For the VS2019 case, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw): *The copy/move (since C++11) may be subject to copy elision*

Comment: @AdrianMole That is for the construction of the exception object, not the parameter in the handler.

Comment: Looks like Wikipedia has an example very similar to yours (without `const` though): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, clang and MSVC are both correct. GCC calls the wrong constructor.

#### There are two separate objects

To understand the required behavior, we must understand that in the following code, there are two objects:

> ```cpp
> int main() {
>     try {
>         throw A{};
>     }
>     catch ( const A ) {
>     }
> }
> ```

Firstly, [[except.throw] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#3) states

> Throwing an exception initializes a temporary object, called the *exception object*. [...]

Secondly [[except.handle] p14.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#14.2) explains,

> The variable declared by the *exception-declaration*, of type *cv* `T` or *cv* `T&`, is initialized from the exception object, of type `E`, as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - otherwise, the variable is copy-initialized from an lvalue of type `E` designating the exception object.

#### GCC calls the wrong constructor

What happens is similar to:

```cpp
A temporary = throw A{};
const A a = temporary;
```

The fact that the variable in the *handler* is `const` doesn't affect the cv-qualifications of the temporary object because they are two separate objects.
The temporary object is not `const`, so `A(A&)` is a better match during initialization. GCC is wrong.

#### MSVC is allowed to perform copy elision

Furthermore, it might possible that copy elision is performed.
The standard even has an example of that in [[except.throw] p7](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#7):

> ```cpp
> int main() {
>   try {
>     throw C();      // calls std​::​terminate if construction of the handler's
>                     // exception-declaration object is not elided
>   } catch(C) { }
> }
> ```

[[class.copy.elision] p1.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.4) confirms that it's allowed, even if cv-qualifications don't match:

> [...] *copy elision*, is permitted in the following circumstances ([...]):
>
> - [...]
> - when the *exception-declaration* of an exception handler declares an object of the same type **(except for cv-qualification)** as the exception object, the copy operation can be omitted by [...]

`A` and `const A` are not the same type, but they only differ in cv-qualification, so copy elision is allowed.

Comment: @HansOlsson you're right. I've misinterpreted the meaning of "except for cv-qualification". I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, GCC bug submitted: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104661